# BASH: When reading user input, Enter brings new line

Tags: bash

I need following sample bash script to behave as follows:

```sh
echo -e "Enter name: \c"
read U_IP_NAME
echo -e "You said your name is : $U_IP_NAME"
```

This will output to:

```
Enter name: Alok
You said your name is : Alok
```

But it I want it to be:

```
You said your name is : Alok
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

**[Solved with solution given by: mouviciel]**

Comment: you don't want the first line "Enter name: Alok"?

Comment: That is exactly what I want.. I want to either echo on last line, or while reading user input, make keyboard's "enter" NOT go to next line.

Comment: If I can stay on the same line, echo -e "\rblahblah" will help(Fill the line again from 0'th offset). But How do I stay on the same line after user hits enter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to move the cursor up one line. This is achieved with `tput cuu1`:

```
echo -e "Enter name: \c"
read U_IP_NAME

tput cuu1

echo -e "Your said your name is : $U_IP_NAME"
```

More info with `man tput` and `man terminfo`.

Answer (score 8):

```
read -p "Enter your uip-name: " U_IP_NAME
```

-p for prompt

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this syntax](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/135884-chomp-like-perl-operator-bash.html):

U_IP_NAME="${U_IP_NAME%\\n}"